# How to maintain codigniter session with AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, session

How to maintain codegnitor session with AJAX?

My session expires when I call more AJAX requests. So how can I maintain both the AJAX request and the session?

Answer (score 0):

use this builtin function to check if ajax call or not and then take desired action.

```
if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
    //action...
}else
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
}
```

you can find some answer here [CodeIgniter Session Disappear Bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573639/codeigniter-session-disappear-bug)

your answer also available here [Codeigniter session bugging out with ajax calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980193/codeigniter-session-bugging-out-with-ajax-calls)
which is :

```
class MY_Session extends CI_Session {
    public function sess_update()
    {
        $CI = get_instance();

        if ( ! $CI->input->is_ajax_request())
        {
            parent::sess_update();
        }
    }
}
```